# Apache Commons Configuration - NodeTreeWalker example?

Tags: java, configuration, apache-commons

It seems that one can walk a Commons hierarchical configuration using a NodeTreeWalker (walkDFS and walkBFS methods), but I am unable to find anywhere a description or example of how to do this.  The JavaDocs are not enough.

Has anyone gotten this to work, and would you share?

Comment: The [tests](https://github.com/apache/commons-configuration/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/configuration2/tree/TestNodeTreeWalker.java) may help.

Comment: Thanks. This grumpy old man longs for the old days where there was documentation other than unit tests 

Comment: Understood - tests can sometimes be a bit cryptic (to me, anyway). They are focused on testing (of course) and not necessarily on explaining.